# Vague edit and unupvote, is this something common?

Tags: discussion, upvotes

I am fairly new to Stack Overflow (Less than a year) and today I saw this in the reputation change:

[image]

When I opened [the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69135738/how-to-check-if-unique-values-of-a-column-has-multiple-occurances-for-different), it got a little weird. I saw it was edited almost after 10 days since it was asked and answered. That too by the user whose answer I accepted. In the edit, only this part was removed: "Any help would mean a lot!". I am assuming the unupvote was also done after that.

I don't have many issues with a mere unupvote, but I am wondering is there any logical reason to do that? Does this happen often in Stack Overflow?

Comment: Votes (up/down) are locked 5 minutes after they are cast, so a user cannot change their vote after that. However, if there is an edit to the post then the votes are unlocked and can be changed.

Comment: @VLAZ yes! I know that. I was asking, what might be the reason (aligning to Stack Overflow etiquette) to remove the 'fluff' 10 days after answering the question so that you can upunvote. Also, as highlighted by Jeanne Dark, I will refrain from adding them in the future.

Comment: We can't know for sure that the editor also unupvoted the question (could have been a coincidence as edits also bump posts). And even if we knew, we can only speculate about the reasons.

Comment: It's nothing to do with etiquette. If one changes one's mind about a vote, and it's locked, performing an otherwise valid edit to "unlock" the vote is perfectly valid.

Comment: I don't know of anything that would forbid people from doing this. It's not really a regulated use of the platform. People are free to cast their votes as they will. They are free to edit as they will. An edit will unlock votes, so they can be changed. Ergo, they are free to upvote, change, unupvote. Such an interaction is neither encouraged nor forbidden. With that said, it's not even clear it was the same user who did all of these actions. I know I've posted an upvote on a post but I just followed it so when it gets edited, I'd remove it.

Comment: @VLAZ you've clearly explained. Got it! And yes, it is not clear it was the same user but at the same time too good to be a mere coincidence. But that doesn't matter. I understood, what was done was absolutely legit.

Comment: "Does this happen often in Stack Overflow?" - the answer to that is usually yes when it comes to Stack Overflow, regardless of the topic ;) Including some bad things, unfortunately. That's the price of popularity, you bump into people a lot. It's best to just keep walking most of the time.

Comment: @Gimby couldn't have summed it up better. The knowledge and great answers here will outclass these anydays. :-)